# How to find rotation degree of part of an image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I capture an image of the rotating disc and I want to rotate the stepper motor by whatever angle the disc is rotated.
Please suggest me some approach to solve this problem.

sample image of the disc

[image]

```py
def mse(img1, img2):
    img1 = cv.cvtColor(img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2 = cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    h, w = img1.shape
    diff = cv.subtract(img1, img2)
    err = np.sum(diff**2)
    mse = err/(float(h*w))
    return mse`
```

```py
for i in range(0,360,5):
    rotate = imutils.rotate(r,i)
    differ = mse(rotate,r)
    print(differ,i)
```

I tried to rotate the original image through 360 degrees and find the angle at which the mean squared error is minimum. but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: use feature detection and matching to find correspondences between the rotating disc in consecutive frames, and then estimate the rotation angle from the correspondences.

Comment: What part is the stepper motor in your image?

Comment: @fmw42 This is just the image of the disc. Its not the image of the stepper motor. I have connected the stepper motor to raspberry pi.

Comment: Do you have an original image where rotation is 0?

Comment: @SRIKANTHS the rotation in your case is the rotation between the green and red colors? or the rotation for the whole pattern? how much is the rotation in your image?(approximately)

Comment: @Bilal i want to find the rotation of the whole pattern

Comment: @SRIKANTHS so what is the reference (zero position) ? Please clarify this point in your question.

Comment: I already asked this question 2 times. If you don't provide an original image (state 0) it's not possible to give you the absolute rotation angle. If you provide the image of step before (state S-1), we can return the relative rotation angle but for that we need a reference.